# adding, copying and creating new csv file

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I got an assignment to import a CSV file with some fields, and I need to create a new CSV file with different fields that contains the original fields (in a different order).

original csv:

```
full name,Posiotion,Phone,Email,LinkedIn,Source,Comment
```

I tried to look up online and this is as far as i got:

```
import csv
with open("mobileTL.csv", 'r') as csv_file:
     reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
     newcsvdict = {"First name": [], "Middle name": [], "Last name": [], "Email": [], "Creation date": [], "Status": [],
 "Position": [], "ID/SSN": [], "Source": [], "Source type": [], "Availability": [], "Salary expectations": [],
    "Phone": [], "Mobile": [], "Street Adress": [], "City": [], "State": [], "Country": [], "Zip": [],
    "LinkedIn URL": [], "Resume file name": [], "Migration ID": [], "Comment": [], "Comment2": []}

next(reader)
for row in reader:
    first = ""
    last = ""
    if row[0] != "":
        first = row[0].split()[0]
        last = row[0].split()[1]
    newcsvdict["First name"].append(first)
    newcsvdict["Last name"].append(last)
    newcsvdict["Phone"].append(row[2])
    newcsvdict["Position"].append(row[1])
    newcsvdict["Email"].append(row[3])
    newcsvdict["Source"].append(row[5])
    newcsvdict["Comment"].append(row[6])
    newcsvdict["LinkedIn URL"].append(row[4])

with open('new.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    w = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, newcsvdict.keys())
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerows(newcsvdict)
```

It does create a new file but for some reason only the header is written.

Comment: Hi please upload the original CSV ("mobileTL.csv")
Or you can write here 2 rows from the original CSV. I will try to help.

Comment: thanks, edited to original post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the reason why it's only writing the header is because you'll get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 29, in <module>
    w.writerows(newcsvdict)
  ...
    wrong_fields = rowdict.keys() - self.fieldnames
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

You need to learn *not* to ignore error messages. The cause of that problem is that you were using [`writerows`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows) (note plural *rows*, which expects an iterable of *rows*) instead of [`writerow`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow) (note singular *row*, which expects just one row). To use `writerows`, you need to pass a **list of dicts** like this:

```
w.writerows([newcsvdict, newcsvdict, newcsvdict])
```

You should be using `writerow`, since you seem to only have 1 row, `newcsvdict`. Though, when I went ahead and did that, the output does not seem to be what you need:

```
First name,Middle name,Last name,Email,Creation date,Status,Position,ID/SSN,Source,Source type,Availability,Salary expectations,Phone,Mobile,Street Adress,City,State,Country,Zip,LinkedIn URL,Resume file name,Migration ID,Comment,Comment2
"['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']",[],"['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC']","['aaa@email.com', 'bbb@email.com', 'ccc@email.com']",[],[],"['Pos1', 'Pos2', 'Pos3']",[],"['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']",[],[],[],"['123', '456', '789']",[],[],[],[],[],[],"['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']",[],[],"['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']",[]
```

That looks weird, because you created a `dict` with a list for each value (ex. `"First name": []`). Maybe that's what you want... but my understanding of your requirement is that you want for the new CSV is to have the same number of rows but different columns.

For that, it does not make sense to store the values as a `list`. One solution is to read one row, create a `dict` for it, then `writerow` it, then just repeat for the steps for all the rows. You can also use `DictReader` to easily access the values from the old CSV as a dict.

```py
with open("new.csv", "w") as new_file:

    new_row = dict.fromkeys([
        "First name", "Middle name", "Last name", "Email", 
        "Creation date", "Status", "Position", "ID/SSN", 
        "Source", "Source type", "Availability", "Salary expectations",
        "Phone", "Mobile", "Street Adress", "City",
        "State", "Country", "Zip", "LinkedIn URL",
        "Resume file name", "Migration ID", "Comment", "Comment2"
    ])

    writer = csv.DictWriter(new_file, fieldnames=new_row.keys())
    writer.writeheader()

    with open("old.csv", 'r') as old_file:
        old_csv = csv.DictReader(old_file)

        for row in old_csv:
            first = ""
            last = ""
            if row["full name"] != "":
                first, last = row["full name"].split()
            new_row["First name"] = first
            new_row["Last name"] = last
            new_row["Phone"] = row["Phone"]
            new_row["Position"] = row["Position"]
            new_row["Email"] = row["Email"]
            new_row["Source"] = row["Source"]
            new_row["Comment"] = row["Comment"]
            new_row["LinkedIn URL"] = row["LinkedIn"]

            writer.writerow(new_row)
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it was very helpful!
also i did manage to make it with this code:

edit: seems i dont know how to  add the code to the comment (says comment is too long)